# Show that the marginal pdf of $Y_1$ is normal given joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

> Let $Y_1,Y_2$ be random variables with joint pdf $$f(y_1, y_2) =
> \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left[{-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2)}\right] \left(
> 1+y_1y_2\exp \left[{-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2-2)}\right]\right)$$
>   Show that the marginal pdf of $Y_1$ is normal.

I am having issues integrating. I know there is some 'trick' to it since it doesn't appear to be possible via traditional techniques. I am unable to find it.

Hopefully, someone can start me in the right direction.

Comment: You shouldn't say $f(Y_1,Y_2);$ rather, that should say $f(y_1,y_2). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are correct. Will change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} & \frac 1 {2\pi} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2)\right] \\
& \left(
1+y_1y_2\exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2-2) \right] \right) \, dy_2 \\[12pt]
= {} & \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {2\pi} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2)\right] \, dy_2 \tag 1 \\[6pt]
& {} + y_1 e^{-2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {2\pi} y_2\exp\left[ -(y_1^2+y_2^2) \right] \, dy_2 \tag 2 \\[6pt] 
\end{align}
Line $(1)$ is a familiar integral. Line $(2)$ is $0$ because an odd function is integrated over an interval symmetric about $0,$ and the integral of the absolute value is finite.

Comment: One thing doesn't quite make sense. Line (1) does not appear to be easy to integrate. Not sure how you would integrate this to get something that is then a normal distribution

Comment: For real exponents: $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$

Comment: Correction:
$$
\begin{align} & \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {2\pi} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2)\right] \, dy_2 \\ {} \\ = {} & \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac 1 2 y_1^2 \right) \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} y_2^2 \right] \, dy_2 \end{align}
$$
The reason why that function of $y_1$ can be pulled out is that as $y_2$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty,$ that function of $y_1$ does not change. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Makes sense now. Thank you for your time and patience

Answer (score 1):

I believe we would have $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2))$ etc so it integrates.

We integrate the joint distribution with respect to $y_2$ from $-\infty$ to $ \infty$.

We separate it into two integrals, one for each term in the final bracket.

The first one integrates to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y_1^2}$, which is a standard Gaussian.

The second one is: $C(y_1) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{-\frac{1}{2}y_2^2})' dy_2 = 0$

Comment: $$\begin{align}f_{\small Y_1,Y_2}(u, v) & =
\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-(u^2+v^2)/2} \left(
1+uv~\mathrm e^{-(u^2+v^2-2)/2}\right)\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2}\\[1ex]&=\left(\frac 1{2\pi}~\mathrm e^{-u^2/2}~\mathrm e^{-v^2/2}+\frac 1{2\pi}u\mathrm e^{-u^2}~v\mathrm e^{-v^2}~\mathrm e\right)\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2}\\[1ex]&=\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-u^2/2}\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-v^2/2}-\frac {\mathrm e}{\pi}u\mathrm e^{-u^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d~2\mathrm e^{-v^2}}{\mathrm d v\qquad}\right)\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2}\end{align}$$Now integrate w.r.t. $v$ over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: yes exactly this